# How can I replace the Nth occurrence of string in a string with regex in obj-C

Tags: objective-c, regex

using something like this I Can replace all occurrences of the string

```
NSString * str = @"monday sunday monday";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"monday" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
NSString *newStr = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length]) withTemplate:@""];
```

how is the correct way to replace only the last occurrence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use negative look ahead as

```
/monday(?!.*monday)/
```

- `(?!.*monday)` negative look ahead. Ensures that the `monday` is not followed by another `monday`

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qS0uS9/1)

Comment: thanks for responding so quick.  that link is helpful.  however i'm actually trying to match something a little more complex.  <script[\s\S]*?>[\s\S]*?<\/script> -- which works fine when matching everything.  however still struggling to match just the last one in a string such as this <script>1</script><script>2</script>

Comment: @myte  Its quite easy. Use the regex `<script[^>]*>[^<]*<\/script>(?!.*<script>)`. https://regex101.com/r/nA4vV0/1

Comment: i actually had to modify this to get it to work.  set it to single line mode etc.  but this got me pretty much where i needed to be

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do this:

1. Create an `NSRegularExpression` which matches *one* occurrence of your string.
2. Call the method `matchesInString:options:range:` returns an `NSArray` of `NSTextCheckingResult` describing all the matches in the string. Select the last element of the array, that is the last match.
3. If you have a simple text replacement you can now use `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:` on a mutable copy of your original string using the range obtained from the `NSTextCheckingResult`. If your replacement text is not simple but constructed based on the match then use `replacementStringForResult:inString:offset:template:` first to obtain the replacement string, then use `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:`.

HTH